# Unable to understand network section of this docker file (zabbix)

Tags: docker, zabbix

I am using this zabbix docker compose file to run zabbix in a VM but I dont understand the subnets that have been defined at the botton.

https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker/blob/4.0/docker-compose_v3_ubuntu_mysql_latest.yaml

[image]

In my internal network I use 2 subnets (one is for private subnet & one is for public subnet e.g. web servers and they start in 10.121.153.x & 10.121.152.x, zabbix is in private subnet)

2 Questions:

1. Would I need the subnet specified in this docker file
2. If I do, what values do I use here?

Zabbix is currently running on Ubuntu VM but all the clients are in Windows. I went down this rabbit hole because I wasnt able to run zabbix_get command from windows machine. This is the command I was trying

```
zabbix_get -s <hostname> -k system.cpu.util[,idle]
```

and got this error

```
zabbix_get [21359]: Check access restrictions in Zabbix agent configuration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker will create two bridge interfaces with those subnets but they will be used by the containers, it means containers will have IPs in those ranges

e.g. `172.16.238.10` will be a container in the frontend network

TL;DR it doesn't matter, they will expose the ports through the docker host IP

Please check they are reachable, is there a firewall blocking these ports?